# "Invalid property name" error when filtering objects based on custom object property

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to filter out objects based on a custom object property called "type" using the following statement:

```
realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).filter("type != %@", MyCustomObject.self)
```

I get the following error then:

> caught "Invalid property name", "Property 'type' not found in object of type 'MyRealmObject'".

The definition of MyRealmObject is following:

```
final class MyRealmObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    var type: MyCustomObject? = nil
}
```

What syntax in Realm's "filter" statement should I use to filter based on "type" property of MyRealmObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make its declaration like that :

```
 @objc dynamic var type: MyCustomObject? = nil
```

adding  @objc dynamic like other properties.